# Data from UI dialog to MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have problem with my web application. I am using MVC3 and not so familiar with it.

I am making functionality for the user to choose application papers to print. I have functions that return stream for the pdf files. But sending data form UI is the trouble. On the page there is button [print] when i push it an UI dialog appears with checkboxes for the user to choose applications. The confirm button should be confirmation on printing.

I am having problem sending data to my controller and return new tab/window with the pdf. I need to send 3 variables to the controller. String that keep info about what to print, id of user and one other variable. I´ve tried AJAX but thats not working. It seems that with AJAX i cannot return pdf in another tab (please correct if i am wrong)

Can someone give me an idea how i can solve this problem? Good solution to send data from dialog window to controller so i can return pdf files in new tab or window.

Edit:

```
public ActionResult GetApplication(ApplicationData appldata)
{
      var application = GetApplicationPapers(appldata.ShowApplOne, appldata.ShowApplTwo); // Applications comes from report server so true or false to determine whether the pdf contains the report or not.
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=application.pdf");
return new FileStreamResult(application, "application/pdf");
}
```

This is how its looks like know. Need to get the values from checkboxes from UI dialog to determine what papers are in the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we see what the action method in your controller that you are trying to POST to looks like? You could essentially just use a normal ActionLink method such as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionMethodName", 
      new {var1 = val1, var2 = val2, var3 = val3}, new {target = "_blank"})
```

Where the 'varX' is the name of your parameters in your action method.

Comment: i am implementing something similar. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Great! If this was helpful for you, would you consider marking the answer as the accepted answer. That way I can get credit and the question can be closed. Thanks!